# Git отказывается пушить изменеия

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

Добрый день друзья, проблема с использованием git, я новичек в этом деле и мало что знаю (в основном стандартное), коммитил, пушил и все хорошо, но недавно попробовал поработать с другого компьютера с тем же проектом и репозиторием (скачал архив с git, добавлял изменеия и все работало исправно) но вернувшись обратно за старый комп и к старой версии проекта git отказывается пушить изменения. Должно быть в сети таких вопросов хватает и прошу воздержаться негатива по поводу моего уже тысячного вопроса, знал бы что искать не обращался бы сюда.

Comment: сначала `git pull` потом `git commit` потом `git push` ...

Comment: Добрый день! Напишите, пожалуйста, какую ошибку Вам возвращает git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну перед тем как коммитить `git commit` и пушить `git push` изменения наверно стоит на старый компьютер запуллить `git pull` к себе изменения из репозитория, ведь на данный момент контент в удаленном и локальном(на старом компьтере) репозиториях различен.

данный вариант, кстати, подойдет если имела место ситуация, что в какой-то момент со старого компьютера просто перестали вносить и пушить изменения, а вся работа проводилась с другого компьютера.

Comment: Благодарю за пояснения что к чему, теперь я точно это запомню, еще раз огромное спасибо!

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev , для ознакомления посоветую [учебник](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).